# Getting route options inside ExceptionListener

Tags: php, symfony

I am working on an ExceptionListener and for some controllers I want errors to be formatted as json responses. I thought I would define an option in `@Route` annotation and then use it in ExceptionListener:

```
/**
 * @Route("/route/path", name="route_name", options={"response_type": "json"})
 */
```

and:

```
class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

but `GetResponseForExceptionEvent` doesn't contain any info about matched route. Is there a way to get the `options` array inside ExceptionListener?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the route name from the attribute request with

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$routeName = $request->attributes->get('_route');
```

then, if you inject the `router` service into your class, you can get the instance of the route with

```
$route = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($routeName);
```

finally

```
$options = $route->getOptions();
echo $options['response_type']
```

---

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class ExceptionListener
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $route = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get(
            $request->attributes->get('_route')
        );

        $options = $route->getOptions();
        // $options['response_type'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Feel like this answer should mention the warning displayed on the `getRouteCollection` method :
`WARNING: This method should never be used at runtime as it is SLOW. You might use it in a cache warmer though.`

Comment: yeah, it should. feel free to make an edit, or submit another answer (happy to upvote it)